# How to check whether the range of selection text intersects with <span> tag

Tags: javascript, html

When I again tries to change the font it changes only the text which is not under any span. Please see the Expectation first.

```
let txt = document.getElementById('txt')
let font = document.getElementsByClassName('form-select')[0];

const fontChange = () => {
    let selectedFont = font.options[font.selectedIndex].value;
    let selection = window.getSelection()
    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
        let range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
        let span = document.createElement('span')
        span.style.fontFamily = selectedFont
        span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
        range.insertNode(span);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
    }
}
```

**Expecting:**

I am make a simple text editor and want to change the font of selected text. And if the text is already under a span which changes its font then make the selected text of font which i recently changed.

Comment: Contenteditable, right? Have you tried using the simplest: `execCommand('fontName', false, selectedFont)` ?

Comment: Yes, contenteditable. I have tried but it is not compatible with all browser.  @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.ececCommand("fontName", false, selectedFont)`.
Tested and working in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge. ([*ecexCommand* compat table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#browser_compatibility))

```js
const elTxt = document.querySelector("#txt");
const elFontFamily = document.querySelector("#fontFamily");

elFontFamily.addEventListener("input", () => {
  document.execCommand("fontName", false, elFontFamily.value);
});
```

```css
#txt{
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<select id="fontFamily">
  <option value="arial, sans-serif">Arial</option>
  <option value="'Courier New', Courier, 'Lucida Sans Typewriter', 'Lucida Typewriter', monospace">Courier</option>
  <option value="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">Verdana</option>
  <option value="Calibri, Candara, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Optima, Arial, sans-serif">Calibri</option>
</select>

<div id="txt" contenteditable=true>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio officiis cupiditate nesciunt, nam ab, temporibus, voluptate repellat commodi ex in, tempore velit sequi cum repudiandae necessitatibus id numquam et inventore.
</div>
```